# How can I obtain a WebResponse in JSON without any whitespace in C#?

Tags: c#, json, formatting, httpwebresponse

I tried using `WebRequest` to call an API endpoint in C# and `WebResponse` to get the response. I am receiving JSON, but the JSON response is filled with a lot of whitespaces, which I'd like to get rid of.

I tried using formatting to get rid of whitespaces. Both `Formatting.None` and `Formatting.Indented`, yet both provide the same JSON output.

This is an example of my code:

```
System.Net.WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();
string content;

using(System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream())) 
{
    content = sr.ReadToEnd();
}

dynamic parsedJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(content);

content = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(parsedJson, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None);
```

This form of JSON string is returned by the code above.

```
"{\n \t\"Success\": \"true\",\n \t\"Status\": 200,\n \t\"SuccessPnrs\": null,\n \t\"RepeatedPnrs\": [\n \t\t\"1184017\"\n \t]\n }"
```

Expected JSON shown here:

```
{"Success": "true","Status": 200,"SuccessPnrs": null,"phone": ["9568523624"]}
```

Comment: What's the *actual* content? Is it a JSON object or a *quoted string* ? JSON.NET doesn't indent the output unless you explicitly tell it to. If you try to deserialize `"{\"banana\":123}"` (including the surrounding double quotes) you'll get a *string* containing `{"banana":123}`, not a `Dictionary<string,int>`. Post code that others can execute to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Again, what is the *actual* source string? Without that, the question will be closed as non-reproducible. JSON.NET would never surround the output in double quotes, much less add newlines and tabs with `Formatting.None`.

Answer (score -1):

If it's only about the \n \t characters I would simply use string.Replace("\t", "") and string.Replace("\n", "")